# Very similar code in two different files, giving two different results when they should give the same result

Tags: c, arrays, printf

This one has me scratching my head. One of these works, the other doesn’t always work, and I can’t tell why. The first batch of code works thus far, but the second batch will occasionally give a different, and incorrect, result from the first. For anyone wondering, this is part of a larger program to solve linear equations I want to make.

The only differences I can note between the two are that the firstEquation array sizes are different, and one of these arrays is declared globally, whereas the other is declared in the main function. I can't see why this would matter though.

```
// First File (THIS ONE WORKS)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int co1 = 0;
int i = 0;
char firstEquation[50];
main ()
    {

        printf("Enter the first equation.. e.g '3x + 2' \n");
        fscanf(stdin, " %99[^\n]", firstEquation); 
        printf("the equation you just entered is: %s \n", firstEquation);
        for (i = 0; i < sizeof(firstEquation)/sizeof(firstEquation[0]); i++)
           {

             if (firstEquation[i] == 'x' || firstEquation[i] == ' ' 
             || firstEquation[i] == '+'||              firstEquation[i] == '-')
               {
                  printf("%d \n", i);
                  co1 = i;
               }

     }
printf("the yintercept of your equation starts at the %d th element in the array", co1+1);
     }
```

Here is the second.

```
// Second File (THIS ONE STUFFS UP SOMETIMES)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int co1 = 0;
int i = 0;

main ()
    {
         char firstEquation[100];
         printf("Enter the first equation.. e.g '3x + 2' \n");
         fscanf(stdin, " %99[^\n]", firstEquation); 
         printf("the equation you just entered is: %s \n", firstEquation);

         for (i = 0; i < sizeof(firstEquation)/sizeof(firstEquation[0]); i++)
              {
                   if (firstEquation[i] == 'x' || firstEquation[i] == ' ' 
                  || firstEquation[i] == '+'|| firstEquation[i] == '-')
                     {
                         printf("%d \n", i);
                         co1 = i;
                     }
              }
    printf("the yintercept of your equation starts at the %d th element in the array", co1+1);
}
```

This is what I input into both files as a way to test it: 65x + 554

```
//OUTPUT OF FIRST BATCH OF CODE (GIVES CORRECT RESULT)
Enter the first equation.. e.g '3x + 2'
65x + 554
the equation you just entered is: 65x + 554
2
3
4
5
the yintercept of your equation starts at the 6 th element in the array
```

And the second.

```
//OUTPUT OF SECOND BATCH OF CODE (GIVES INCORRECT RESULT)
Enter the first equation.. e.g '3x + 2'
65x + 554
the equation you just entered is: 65x + 554
2
3
4
5
10
the yintercept of your equation starts at the 11 th element in the array
```

Comment: can you memset your memory before using it... I mean "memset(firstEquation, 0x00, sizeof(firstEquation));"

Comment: this parameter of the fscanf() function: " %99[^\n]" is not correct in the first program, because the firstEquation is only 50 char long, not 99

Comment: fscanf() does not append a null byte, so either the input buffer must be pre-initialized to all '\0' or a search for the '\n' and replaced with a '\0'

Comment: on a character array, this code: sizeof(firstEquation[0] will always be 1.  In actuality, the code should stop when the string terminator byte is encountered

Comment: Thanks a heap for your replies guys, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second program invoke Undefined Behaviour as you try to access uninitialized locations.

In the first program,since `firstEquation` is global,it will be initialized to 0 while in the second program,it will remain uninitialized thus invoking UB when you access these locations.

You can fix this by initializing `firstEquation` in the second program to 0 by using

```
char firstEquation[100]={0};
```

or you can use `memset` to do it:

```
memset(firstEquation,0,sizeof(firstEquation));
```

---

```
sizeof(firstEquation)/sizeof(firstEquation[0])
```

in the `for` loop will probably return 50 for the first program and 100 for the second. Thus,the loop executes 50 times in the first program and 100 times in the second program.But you only need to loop the number of characters entered times.So,use

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(firstEquation); i++)
```

Also,

```
fscanf(stdin, " %99[^\n]", firstEquation);
```

in the first program should be

```
fscanf(stdin, " %49[^\n]", firstEquation);
```

as `firstEquation` is 50 elements long and not 100. Use `int main()` instead of `main()` and add a `return 0;` just before closing `main`.